# C# apply sequence number to group items

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to group a collection of objects, sorting by Name, but I also want to set a sequential InstanceID property within each group, such that I have the following:

```
Name="A", InstanceID=0
Name="A", InstanceID=1
Name="A", InstanceID=2
Name="B", InstanceID=0
Name="C", InstanceID=0
Name="C", InstanceID=1
Name="C", InstanceID=2
Name="D", InstanceID=0
Name="D", InstanceID=1
Name="D", InstanceID=2
Name="D", InstanceID=3
```

etc.

I'm assuming there is some projection applied via LINQ after `GroupBy` but I'm unaware of how to use an accumulator or index within the `Select` or `SelectMany`.

I do not want to create a new collection, but only modify the existing collection, setting `InstanceID` on each element.

Comment: you want groups the elements or sorts by 2 properties?

Comment: I want to group by the Name property. Within each group, I want to set a sequential index to an InstanceID property (like a serial number).

Comment: Do you mean that for each element of each group you want to set the sequential index within that group?

Comment: `...OrderBy(o => o.Name).ThenBy(o => o.InstanceId);` or `...GroupBy(o => o.Name).Select(g => g.OrderBy(o => o.InstanceId));`

Comment: @Kenneth Yes. And I don't want to create a copy of the original collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `GroupBy` by `Name`, then for each group sets the `InstanceID` property:

```
var groups = objects.GroupBy(m => m.Name);

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in group)
        item.InstanceID = index++;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can create extension methods `ForEach` receiving the item and the index:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in collection)
            action(item);
    }

    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Action<T, int> action)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in collection)
            action(item, index++);
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
var groups = objects.GroupBy(m => m.Name);
groups.ForEach(g => g.ForEach((o, i) => o.InstanceID = i));
```

Comment: Does this operate on the original `objects` list, or just a copy of it via `groups`?

Comment: if the objects are reference type, then yes, the original models will be modified.

Comment: @MarkRichman: if you want groups the elements then a new collection needs to be created, but contains the original elements, then just need to set `InstanceID` property in each element

Comment: This did *exactly* what I wanted. I'm going to leave the question open a bit, but I should be accepting this answer shortly. Thanks!!!

Comment: @MarkRichman: Essentially, you can not set `InstanceID` using *Linq* since there is no `ForEach` method (although you can create it easily), and Select creates a new object.

Comment: I actually like the first implementation without the nested `ForEach` extensions. Much easier to comprehend and debug.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GroupBy` and then the overload of `Select` that projects the index:

```
var groups = objects
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(g => g.Select((obj, index) => new { Object = obj, Index = index }));

foreach(var grp in groups)
    foreach(var x in grp)
        x.Object.InstanceID = x.Index;
```

If you aren't really interested in the groups and you want to flatten them after you've determined the indexes you could also use `SelectMany` and a single loop:

```
var items = objects
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((obj, index) => new { Object = obj, Index = index }));

foreach(var x in items)
    x.Object.InstanceID = x.Index;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an overload of select that gives you the index

```
var list = otherList.Select((model, index) => new { Index=index, ... })
```

In you case to group it could be used like this

```
list = list
        .OrderBy(m => m.Name)
        .GroupBy(m => m.Name)
        .SelectMany(g => g.Select((m, i) => new NameOfClass { InstanceID = i, Name = m.Name } ))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: My requirement is to update the collection in place, setting InstanceID.

Comment: You could just iterate the result and set the `InstanceID` of each object afterwards, the purpose of linq/functional programming is to not have any sideeffects.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using query expression:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Instance {get; set;}
}

Person p1 = new Person {Name ="C"};
Person p2 = new Person {Name ="B"};
Person p3 = new Person {Name ="A"};
Person p4 = new Person {Name ="C"};
Person p5 = new Person {Name ="C"};
Person p6 = new Person {Name ="B"};

var persons = new List<Person>{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6};

var result = from p in persons
             group p by p.Name into g orderby g.Key
             from gr in g.Select((x,i) => new {Value = x, Index = i})
             select gr;

result.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Value.Instance = x.Index);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple I would use a class like this:

```
public class StudentSubject
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Student { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

}
```

The list would have to populated somehow:

```
        var list = new List<StudentSubject>();
        list.Add(new StudentSubject
        {
            Subject = "Physics",
            Student = "Steve"
        });
        list.Add(new StudentSubject
        {
            Subject = "Physics",
            Student = "Sarah"
        });
....
```

Then loop over the list:

```
        var subjectGroups = from subjectStudent in list
                            group subjectStudent by subjectStudent.Subject;

        foreach(var subjectNameGroup in subjectGroups)
        {
            int id = 0;
            foreach (var studentSubject in subjectNameGroup)
            {
                studentSubject.ID = id;
                id++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that OP has already a class and the term "collection of objects" just means a `List<SomeClass>` or `SomeClass[]`. Apart from that this is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36064265/284240) answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter correct. This collection already exists as ObservableCollection<T>

Comment: I thought it might be nice to qualify my answer with some additional information.  It makes the code easier to read.